# Neo4j Collaborative Filtering (CF) recommendation query using Pearson

Tags: neo4j, collaborative-filtering, pearson

Hi everyone at Stackoverflow,

I want to understand query that is using Pearson.

What can be `nom` and `denom`?

What is `r1: r1` and `r2: r2`?

And I don't understand what is `r.r1.rating` and `r.r2.rating`.

This query should be recommending Movies that are rated by other Users.

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: 3})-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie)
WITH u1, avg(r.rating) AS u1_mean
MATCH (u1)-[r1:RATED]->(m:Movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(u2)
WITH u1, u1_mean, u2, COLLECT({r1: r1, r2: r2}) AS ratings WHERE size(ratings) > 10
MATCH (u2)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie)
WITH u1, u1_mean, u2, avg(r.rating) AS u2_mean, ratings
UNWIND ratings AS r
WITH sum( (r.r1.rating-u1_mean) * (r.r2.rating-u2_mean) ) AS nom,
     sqrt( sum( (r.r1.rating - u1_mean)^2) * sum( (r.r2.rating - u2_mean) ^2)) AS denom,
     u1, u2 WHERE denom <> 0
WITH u1, u2, nom/denom AS pearson
ORDER BY pearson DESC LIMIT 10
MATCH (u2)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) WHERE NOT EXISTS( (u1)-[:RATED]->(m) )
RETURN m.name, SUM( pearson * r.rating) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25
```

The output is as follows:

"m.name"                     │"score"           │

│"Sleepless in Seattle"      │25.859451877376813│

│"The Tunnel"                │22.652532472101605│

│"Beetlejuice"               │22.21835919736008 │

│"Shriek If You Know What .."│21.935357890253528│

│"Dawn of the Dead"          │21.421377433824798│

│"The Prisoner of Zenda"     │21.225502683325033│

│"The Talented Mr. Ripley"   │20.83938743140176 │

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So the formula for Pearson is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample

nom is simply the numerator of that formula, defined here:
"WITH sum( (r.r1.rating-u1_mean) * (r.r2.rating-u2_mean) ) AS nom,"

Likewise, denom is the denominator.

I'm less clear on the other two questions, but hopefully this helps!